# Documentation on gRaphael Graphing

Tags: javascript, charts, raphael, graphael

I've been trying out different JavaScript based charting options. I love Highcharts but also wanted to take a look at gRaphael. I've found that the gRaphael documentation is really lacking and [the efforts of kennyshen](https://github.com/kennyshen/g.raphael) also do not cover a lot of the things. As a result, I'm having a ton of problem charting with gRaphael. Could someone point me to a robust documentation?

Also can I achieve similar charting with only Raphael? If so, can someone point me out to a tutorial of sorts. My primary requirement is bar/column charts.

Comment: I think that gRaphael based on 2.0 is being updated now. Dmitry Baranovskiy, the creator of Raphael, transfered the project to someone else some days ago, maximum 1 month. More details and the current maintainers can be found on raphaeljs' twitter account. Some documentation is available, like here http://jburrows.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/documentation-for-graphael-g-line-js/ but you can also view the source code of the examples and learn a thing or two

Comment: Hmmm. I've been through the text you suggested. Thanks anyways. I was hoping to find some more details on bar charts. I could go through the source, yes, but we are in a serious time crunch in our project at the moment.

Comment: http://g.raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Rgraph (http://www.rgraph.net/), which is easy to implement and well documented with lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a decent amount of research on JS charting libraries. I personally think High Charts and jqPlot are the best looking with adequate documentation. You can take a look and see what you think:

jqPlot Doc:

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html

High Charts Doc:

http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use